# Приставка пре- или при-?

Tags: орфография

В каких случаях пишется приставка "при-", а в каких "пре-"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Приставка "пре-" означает превосходную степени понятия. А также как короткая форма приставки "пере-".
Например: *превосходный, предобрый, преинтересный, преступление*
"При-" употребляется в значении присоединения, приближения, доведения чего-то до конца или неполного действия.
Пример: *приехать, приделать, приоткрыть.*

Answer (score 2):

Приставка пре- указывает на:

1. высшую степень качества. Заменяется по смыслу словом "очень". Предобрый = очень добрый;
2. перемену действия, передачу, прекращение. Близка к "пере-" («по-иному», «через») прервать (перестать), преградить - перегородить, превратить.

Приставка при- указывает на:
1. сближение: пришкольный, приклеить;
2. неполнота действия = чуть-чуть: присесть - чуть-чуть сесть;
3. доведение до конца: приспособить.

Ещё есть дополнительные (уловки) [правила по поводу приставок при- и пре-](http://polyidioms.narod.ru/index/pravopisanie_pristavok_pre_i_pri/0-256).
Слова с приставкой при- со значением сближения имеют синоним с приставкой под- и антоним приставкой у- или от-. Например: прикреплять – подкреплять - откреплять.
Также они требуют пояснительных слов с предлогом «в» или «к», отвечающих на вопросы «куда?», «к чему?» (приспособиться к чему? – к новым условиям; приехать куда? – в деревню). 
К словам с приставкой пре- не подобрать таких антонимов и синонимов, они также не требуют таких, как указано выше, пояснительных слов.

Также есть слова иностранного происхождения, в которых при- и пре- это не приставка, или она имеет другое, тоже заимствованное значение. Эти слова надо запомнить.

Comment: сближение - это процесс. И слово "пришкольный" - это не сближение, а пространственная близость (отдельный пункт правила).

Answer (score 0):

Всё зависит от значения слова. Приставка при- пишется, если слово имеет значение приближения, присоединения, нахождения вблизи, неполного действия. Прибежать, приклеить, приморский, прилечь. Приставка пре- пишется в значении "очень" и близка по смыслу приставке пере-. Прехорошенький, преступить закон. Следует различать пары: преемник - перенимает, приёмник - принимает, приближает. Презирать - очень не любить, призирать - приближать, заботиться.

Answer (score 0):

> Цель написания этого ответа - кратко, красиво и ясно представить это правило.

#### Приставка `пре` пишется, если...

- Приставка близка по значению к приставки `пере`.
- Имеет значение `очень` (предобрый).

#### Приставка `при` пишется, если...

- В значение **при**соединения, **при**ближения, **при**бавления, примеры сразу в самом пункте правила.
- В значение пространственной близости (прибрежный).
- Неполнота действия (придвинуть).
- Полнота действия....  То есть доведения его до конца (придумать).

Answer (score -1):

"Призирать - приближать, заботиться".
Скорее - присматривать, приглядывать, заботиться. (Ср. зрить, зрение, беспризорник, надзор, призор